# how to make mysql databse encrypted?

Tags: mysql, encryption, innodb

I want to make database encrypted so whenever someone hack our database he is not able to see user information.

I already tried file_key_management but it encrypted table file.

Comment: Encryption-at-rest vs dynamic?  Where are the decryption keys to be held?  Etc, etc.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on MySQL 5.7 tablespace encryption? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html